# Animation with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone help me get this series of JS animate steps into a loop where just the first 3 lines are performed over and over with the "top" element will decreasing by 50 until it reaches 50, then loop finishes. I have created a fiddle to demonstrate how I need it to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/Nr5G5/6/. I have tried everything I know to get this to work but it's beyond the scope of my knowledge.

```
$( "#left_door" ).animate({ "width": "10%" }, 2000);
$( "#left_door" ).animate({ "width": "100%" }, 3000, function(){
$( "#elevator" ).animate({ "top": "450px" }, 3000, function(){...
```

in my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/Nr5G5/7/ the door opens and closes while div div is moving and I am trying to get the door to wait til the div has stopped before opening

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Likely be easier if you split the functionality into two parts: the click, and a function that makes the elevator move from where it is to a target floor. Then you can simply have the function call itself until it reaches the target floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you're not waiting for the previous floor change to complete. It likely can be fixed to continue using the while loop, however, i found it easier to just split the functionality into a function with a callback.

I also changed the initial state of the door to be open for simplicity, you may want to change it back to closed and have it open and close before it starts it's first move. Maybe even move the opening and closing of the door into it's own function.

```
var current_floor = -1,
    floor_stops = ["400", "300", "250"],
    moving = false;

function changeFloor(floor, callback) {
    if (floor === current_floor || moving) {
        callback();
        return;
    }
    moving = true;
    $("#left_door").animate({width: "100%"}, 3000, function () {
        $("#elevator").animate({top: floor_stops[floor]}, 5000, function () {
            $("#left_door").animate({width: "10%"}, 2000, function() {
                moving = false;
                current_floor = floor;
                callback();
            });
        });
    });
}

$("#start_btn").click(function () {
    changeFloor(0, function(){
        changeFloor(1, function(){
            changeFloor(2, $.noop);
        });
    });
});

// this is extra, it just creates floor buttons
floor_stops.forEach(function (top, i) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Floor " + i;
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        changeFloor(i, $.noop);
    }, false);
    btn.style.position = "absolute";
    btn.style.top = top + "px";
    btn.style.left = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nr5G5/10/

Comment: Thanks, this looks great Kevin and it helps with my knowledge.  I will mess with the door, probably do like you recommend.  Had a hard time breaking out of the idea of having the 3 nice neat animation steps mentality.  So anyway I have a bank of check boxes that push the floor numbers onto the floor_stops array, just made the array up here for simplicity.  Thanks again.